# Does anyone else see this weird spacing on our Markdown help page?

Tags: bug, design

https://tex.stackexchange.com/editing-help

Take a look at the (lack of) space between the header and the expander triangle.  Doesn't seem very 'touchable' in its current state.

[image]

Using Safari.

Comment: Yes, I see it, too (FF 39.0)

Comment: Yes, FF 39 on Linux: Basically no spacing there

Comment: Same on Google Chrome (43.0.2357.134 m) with Windows7.

Comment: @MarcvanDongen Presumably, some space should be introduced to make it not look like crap. Maybe an enspace. Anybody with eyes can see the problem and intuit the 'solution'.

Comment: @MarcvanDongen Meta isn't always a place for discussion. Just peruse the [tag:bug] tag if you don't believe me :)